# Magento 2 : Activation/Deactivation and uninstallation module event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extensions

I am writing an extension for Magento 2. When my extension is activated, I want to send a request to my backend to register a merchant. And when the merchant deletes my extension, I also send a DELETE request to my backend.

How can I listen to the Magento activation/deactivation and uninstallation event? (In Wordpress we have those hooks)

What package do we use for HTTP request in magento2?

Thank you very much!