# Where to save jwt token Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am building a module for magento2. My module needs to interact with my own server, so I decide to use ZendClient for it.

When the merchant activates my module, I send a request to my server to register a merchant then receive a jwt token for future API call. My questions are:

1. Where should I save the jwt token?
2. I need to send request to my server when the merchant activates my module? How to do it?

[Magento 2 : Activation/Deactivation and uninstallation module event](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316983/magento-2-activation-deactivation-and-uninstallation-module-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is your answer
First Create a new Module

in your `TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'TheRealHunzik_ApiActivation',
    __DIR__
);
```

create `TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TheRealHunzik_ApiActivation" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Create admin configurations fields

in your `TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\etc\adminhtml\system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custommodule" translate="label" sortOrder="650">
            <label>Custom Module</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="activatemodule" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>API Token Module</label>
            <tab>custommodule</tab>
            <resource>TheRealHunzik_ApiActivation::config_setting</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <field id="enable_frontend" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable on frontend</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="token_key" translate="label" type="hidden" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="0" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label></label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="status" translate="label" type="hidden" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="0" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label></label>
                </field>
                <field id="activate_now" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label></label>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="activatemodule/general/enable_frontend">1</field>
                    </depends>
                    <frontend_model>TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\ActivateNow</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

set initial values for newly created feilds

`TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\etc\config.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <activatemodule>
            <general>
                <enable_frontend>1</enable_frontend>
                <status>0</status>
            </general>
        </activatemodule>
    </default>
</config>
```

add frontend module to create a Button field using HTML

`TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\ActivateNow.php`

```
<?php

namespace TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

class ActivateNow extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @var $template
     */
    protected $_template = 'TheRealHunzik_ApiActivation::form/field/activatenow.phtml';
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param Context
     * @param array
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Render a Component
     * @param AbstractElement
     * @return AbstractElement
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }
    /**
     * Getting component Html
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Get Submit Url
     * @return url
     */
    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('custom/activate/index');
    }
    /**
     * Get Button Html
     * @return var
     */
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $status=$this->_scopeConfig->getValue("activatemodule/general/status", "websites");
        /* If Token is set means No button will be Shown */
        if(!$status){
            $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'activate_now',
                    'label' => __('Activate Now'),
                    'class' => 'primary'
                ]
            );
            return $button->toHtml();
        }
        
    }
}
```

create a button in your phtml file and on click make a request to controller
`TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\view\adminhtml\templates\form\field\activatenow.phtml`

```
<script>
require(
    ['jquery','mage/url','Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'], 
    function($,url,malert) {
        $('#activate_now').click(function() {
            var requestUrl='<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>';
            console.log(requestUrl);
            $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: requestUrl,
                  data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                  dataType: "json",
                  showLoader: true,
            }).done(function( response ) {
                malert({
                    title: $.mage.__(response.result),
                    content: $.mage.__(response.message),
                    actions: {
                        always: function(){}
                    }
                });
                if(response.result){
                    $('#activate_now').hide();
                    
                }
            });
        });
 });
</script>
<?php echo $block->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

Now create route and controller to Call API

in `TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\etc\adminhtml\route.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation ="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="TheRealHunzik_ApiActivation" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

now create a controller and add your code to call API and get token_key from server

`TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\Controller\Adminhtml\Activate.php`

```
<?php

namespace TheRealHunzik\ApiActivation\Controller\Adminhtml\Activate;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory  = $resultJsonFactory;  
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute Function
     *
     * @return JsonFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /* Call activation API here  */

        /* If you are activated successfully save Token Key in "activatemodule/general/token_key"*/
        
        
        /* Set "activatemodule/general/status" in Core Config to 1 */



        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data=[
            'result'    =>   'success',
            'message'   =>   'Activated SuccessFully'
        ];
        $resultJson->setData($data);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

Full Code Available [Here on GitHub](https://github.com/TheRealHunzik/ApiActivation)

Comment: Hey, you forget to push the code. Can I have your FB or sth that I can reach you.? Thanks

Comment: okay sure connect with me on facebook I will send you package there!

Comment: connect me Here https://www.facebook.com/Hunzukuxh